# git : fatal: Pathspec 'ConsoleApp1/Class1.cs' is in submodule 'ConsoleApp1'

Tags: visual-studio, git, контроль-версий

Эксперементирую с командами git и сталкнулся с такой ошибкой:

Изменил файл, который уже отслеживался и получаю такой результат git status:

> Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add ..." to update
>   what will be committed)   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard
>   changes in working directory)
>
> modified:   ConsoleApp1/Class1.cs

Ок, значит нужно выполнить git add "ConsoleApp1/Class1.cs" и получаю такой результат:

> git : fatal: Pathspec 'ConsoleApp1/Class1.cs' is in submodule
>   'ConsoleApp1' At line:1 char:1
>   + git add "ConsoleApp1/Class1.cs"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (fatal: Pathspec...e 'ConsoleApp1':String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Что я делаю не так?

Если не конкретный файл добавлять, а все, то все нормально отрабатывает.

Команды вбиваю в Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 0):

Слово «submodule» в сообщении об ошибке говорит, что вы используете подмодули.

Это отдельный репозиторий внутри основного, и работать с ним нужно отдельно. В частности, для выполнения `git add` нужно быть внутри репозитория, т.е. внутри подпапки ConsoleApp1.

```
cd ConsoleApp1
git add Class1.cs
```

Подробнее читайте в [git-book, глава 7.11 Подмодули](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8)